# Angular 12 trying to pass data to a dynamic loaded component, but uncertain on how to achieve it

Tags: angular, angular12

I have a component that I'm loading dynamically.

Here is the code:

app.component.ts

```typescript
    @ViewChild(InjectDirective, { static: true }) injectComp!: InjectDirective;
    
      componentFactory: any;
      constructor(private componentFactoryResolver: ComponentFactoryResolver) {}
    
      add(): void {
        this.componentFactory = this.componentFactoryResolver.resolveComponentFactory(ModalComponent);
        const viewContainerRef = this.injectComp.viewContainerRef;
        viewContainerRef.createComponent(this.componentFactory);
      }
```

app.component.html

```html
    <button (click)="add()">Dynamically Add Component</button>  
    <ng-template appInject></ng-template>
```

and the directive:

```typescript
    import { Directive, ViewContainerRef } from '@angular/core';
    
    @Directive({
      selector: '[appInject]'
    })
    export class InjectDirective {
    
      constructor(public viewContainerRef: ViewContainerRef) {}
    
    }
```

I need to pass some data to the component that's dynamically loaded.

How do I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `createComponent` function is returning the component's instance. You can solve this problem by passing this example as a parameter to the directive.

app.component.ts

```ts
add(): void {
  this.componentFactory =
    this.componentFactoryResolver.resolveComponentFactory(ModalComponent);
  const viewContainerRef = this.injectComp.viewContainerRef;
  const component = viewContainerRef.createComponent<ModalComponent>(
    this.componentFactory
  );
  // pass component to directive
  this.injectComp.modalComponent = component.instance;
}
```

inject.directive.ts

```ts
@Input() set modalComponent(component: ModalComponent) {
   // You can pass parameter here
   component.zIndex = Math.random() * 10;
}
```

Example Project here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-ooghrz?file=src%2Fapp%2Finject.directive.ts

Comment: So, if I had (for example) an object in app.component.ts data = {type:"Fiat", model:"500", color:"white"};  how do I pass it to my component (ModalComponent) ?

Comment: in add function after this line `const component = viewContainerRef.createComponent...` it works if you add `component.instance.data = this.data` @deszok

Comment: Like this? add(): void {
    this.componentFactory = this.componentFactoryResolver.resolveComponentFactory(ModalComponent);
    this.componentFactory.instance.data = this.data
    const viewContainerRef = this.injectComp.viewContainerRef;
    viewContainerRef.createComponent(this.componentFactory);
  }.

Comment: No after like this `this.componentFactory =
    this.componentFactoryResolver.resolveComponentFactory(ModalComponent);
  const viewContainerRef = this.injectComp.viewContainerRef;
  const component = viewContainerRef.createComponent<ModalComponent>(this.componentFactory); 
component.instance.data = this.data;
`

Comment: I get this error: "Property 'data' does not exist on type 'ModalComponent'" for this line: component.instance.data = this.data;

Comment: The variable name `data` was an example. You should send it to whatever variable you want to send in ModalComponent.

Comment: Perfect! thanks!